# Why doesn't my state update in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand why my state isn't updating in this code. I reviewed an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716581/why-isnt-my-state-updating) but doesn't seem to answer my question b/c I only have one component to bind to.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={
            headline: 'this is headline state',
            cat: 25
        }
    }

    update(e) {
        this.setState=({headline: e.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        let headline=this.state.headline
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text"
                onChange={this.update.bind(this)} />
                <h1>{headline}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    headline: React.PropTypes.string,
    cat: React.PropTypes.number
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

Comment: Also a bit of boilerplate reduction, you don't need to use constructor to set default state, you can use `componentWillMount() { this.setState( { your initial state }) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` is method not property, remove `=`

```
update(e) {
   this.setState({ headline: e.target.value });
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/39942/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a type in your code:

```
this.setState=({headline: e.target.value})
```

Should be

```
this.setState({headline: e.target.value})
```

The rest looks fine.